# Extending SupportMapFragment shows an all black screen when the fragment is loaded

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am converting a program to use Fragments, so it now has one actual Activity, and everything else is Fragments of one type or another.

So the hierarchy of ErrandMapActivity is:

```
Object -> Fragment -> SupportMapFragment -> MapViewActivity -> ErrandMapActivity
```

For ErrandAssistantFreeMainActivity:

```
Object -> Context -> ContextWrapper -> ContextThemeWrapper -> Activity -> FragmentActivity -> ErrandAssistantMainActivity -> ErrandAssistantFreeMainActivity
```

So the activity loads the main fragmentlayout that then loads the mapview, and I see the textview that is in the fragment, but the map is not visible.

For ErrandMapActivity, which is a Fragment, it loads this layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    class="com.jblack.android.errandrouter.activity.ErrandMapActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    map:mapType="normal"
    map:uiCompass="true"
    map:uiRotateGestures="true"
    map:uiScrollGestures="true"
    map:uiTiltGestures="true"
    map:uiZoomControls="true"
    map:uiZoomGestures="true" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In `ErrandMapActivity` I have this method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment_layout, container,
            false);
    return view;
}
```

In `MapViewActivity.onResume` I have `mMapView = getMap()` and I have these values, to verify that the SupportMapFragment actually instantiated a map:

```
mMapView = GoogleMap (id=830023276792)
  fQ = IGoogleMapDelegate$a$a (id=830023235664)
     b = ag (id=830023221320)
  fR = null
```

The one Activity in this application uses this layout, so this is loaded then the map fragment is instantiated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/allFragmentsFrameLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="com.jblack.android.errandrouter.activity.ErrandMapActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

So, I know that my fragment that extends `SupportMapFragment` is being loaded, so what might need to be done in order to get the map loaded?

Comment: This code is exceptionally confusing. You have two fragments that think they are activities (`MapViewActivity`, `ErrandMapActivity`), with an unclear relationship between them, and you have no activities (despite having multiple things named `...Activity`). Hence, I have no idea what you are trying to do, let alone why it is not working. Use Hierarchy View to see where your `MapView` went.

Comment: @CommonsWare - I am modifying a program to use Fragments but didn't feel like changing all the names. That is why they are named activity.

Comment: @JamesBlack Seems like a bad practice. You (or some unfortunate colleague) will have to maintain this in the future. You are creating debt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got rid of your map.

`ErrandMapActivity` overrides `onCreateView()` and throws away the map (obtained from the superclass), replacing it with a `LinearLayout` and a `TextView`.

You need to not do that. :-)

For example, this might work:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // one seriously hopes that you never use mContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment_layout, container,
            false);

    View whatYourParentGaveYou=super.onCreateView(inflater, view, savedInstanceState);

    view.addView(whatYourParentGaveYou, /* insert valid LinearLayout.LayoutParams here */

    return view;
}
```

All those `map` attributes on the `LinearLayout` will be ignored, in all likelihood, so set them up via Java code.

Comment: I just used the SupportMapFragment directly and it worked as expected so I will just write a new fragment to interact with the map from there, which is probably a better design.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out as it is the black background of the activity shown. User custom theme of white background or any default with white. for E.x

@dimen/actionbar_height
        @android:color/white

and set it to activity in manifest. And keep in mind that this white background affect background if you are using any dialogues.